# SQL: Updating using timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with a column called 'updated'. When a new row is CREATED, the column automatically inserts the current time. However, I'd like to UPDATE the column as well..any input on how to do this? Here's my update statement (doesn't have the 'updated' column yet):

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE documents SET company = '$company',claimnumber = '$claimnumber',fullname = '$fullname',dateofloss = '$dateofloss',foruser = '$foruser' "."WHERE doc_id =".$doc_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `updated` column to be updated on update, assign `NOW()` to it in your query.

Comment: Wow, that was simple enough. Thanks!

Comment: But that requires modifying every `UPDATE documents` (both present and future ones), that may or may not be a massive pile of unpleasantness.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html), something like this:

```
create trigger updated_is_now before update on documents
for each row set NEW.updated = now();
```

Then you can send in your usual SQL `UPDATE` statements and the trigger will, effectively, add `updated = now()` to the `SET` clause.

Comment: @mu: I have an if statement at the end (see my original post), only allowing one row to be changed at a time. But this would be useful if there were many rows to be edited at once, right?

Comment: @Zakman411: The trigger would work just as well with one row or many.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE `documents` 
ADD COLUMN `UpdatedDate` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

Edit: To change...

```
ALTER TABLE `documents` 
MODIFY `updated` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I don't want to add the column though, it already exists (since the entire row was created initially). Is there a way to UPDATE only?

Comment: @Zakman411: ["With both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clauses, the column has the current timestamp for its default value, and is automatically updated."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp.html), the ON UPDATE bit has the same effect as my trigger approach. So the updated MODIFY version of the ALTER TABLE would do the trick.